# Word problem about percentages. Represent as an equation and explain

Tags: word-problem

A vendor sells only Product A, for \$6, and Product B, for \$21. If Q% of the products sold are Product B, and if T% of the total revenue comes from sales of Product B, find Q in terms of T.

I can not get the algebraic equation right.

Comment: I can not get the algebraic equation right.I do understand the whole context but stuck on getting the equation out of the given information.Can somebosy please represent it algebraicly and explain it?Thank you Reply

Comment: You can add this information by clicking "edit".

Comment: $T*(21*Q + (1 - Q)6) = 21*Q$

Comment: 40T/(140−T) is the right anwer btw but i dont know how to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be the quantity of Product A sold.  Let $b$ be the quantity of Product B sold.  Then the *fraction* of products sold that are Product A is
$$  \frac{a}{a+b}  $$
and the fraction of products sold that are Product B is
$$  \frac{b}{a+b}  \text{.}  $$
(Note that these sum to $\frac{a}{a+b} + \frac{b}{a+b} = \frac{a+b}{a+b} = 1$, so we have accounted for all the products sold.)  To convert either of these fractions to a percentage, multiply by $100\%$.

Revenue from Product A is $\$6 a$ and revenue from Product B is $\$21 b$, so total revenue is $\$6 a + \$21 b$.  The fractions of revenue from Product A and Product B are, respectively,
$$  \frac{\$6 a}{\$6 a + \$21 b} \text{ and } \frac{\$21 b}{\$6 a + \$21 b}  \text{.}  $$
As before, we can convert either to percentage by multiplying by $100\%$.

We are told that 
$$  Q\% = \frac{b}{a+b} \times 100\%  $$
and 
$$  T\% = \frac{\$21 b}{\$6 a + \$21 b} \times 100\%  \text{.}  $$

Now we compute, first cancelling "$\%$" and "$\$$", \begin{align*}
\frac{T}{100} &= \frac{21 b}{6 a + 21 b}  \text{, so }  \\
1 - \frac{T}{100} &= \frac{6 a + 21 b}{6 a + 21 b} - \frac{21 b}{6 a + 21 b}  \\
    &= \frac{6 a}{6 a + 21 b}  \text{.}
\end{align*}  Then, finding a combination that gives us $a+b$, \begin{align*}
6 \cdot \frac{T}{100} + 21 \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{T}{100} \right)
    &= \frac{6 \cdot 21 b}{6 a + 21 b} + \frac{21 \cdot 6 a}{6 a + 21 b}  \\
    &= \frac{6 \cdot 21 (a+b)}{6 a + 21 b}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
We want that $a+b$ in the denominator so we take reciprocals and use $\frac{T}{100}$ to get the lone $b$ in the numerator.
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{6 \cdot \frac{T}{100} + 21 \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{T}{100} \right)}
    &= \frac{6 a + 21 b}{6 \cdot 21 (a+b)}  \text{, so}  \\
6 \cdot \frac{T}{100} \cdot \frac{1}{6 \cdot \frac{T}{100} + 21 \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{T}{100} \right)}
    &= 6 \cdot \frac{21 b}{6 a + 21 b} \cdot \frac{6 a + 21 b}{6 \cdot 21 (a+b)}  \\
    &= \frac{6 \cdot 21 b}{6 \cdot 21 (a+b)}  \\
    &= \frac{b}{a+b}  \\
    &= \frac{Q\%}{100\%}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

This gives \begin{align*}
Q &= \frac{6T}{6 \cdot \frac{T}{100} + 21 \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{T}{100} \right)}  \cdot \frac{100}{100}  \\
    &= \frac{600T}{6 T + 21 \cdot \left( 100 - T \right)}  \\
    &= \frac{600T}{6 T + 2100 - 21T}  \\
    &= \frac{600T}{2100 - 15T }  \\
    &= \frac{15 \cdot 40T}{15 \cdot (140 - T) }  \\
    &= \frac{40T}{140 - T}  \text{.}
\end{align*}